# Passing JQuery variable to code behind in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have been trying for a while to get the variable passed from the JQuery function to the code behind so that I can enter it into a database via an SQL statement.  However, I never seem to get the variable passed.  Or if it is passing, I can't seem to get it to display to make sure it has been passed.  Can anyone see what's wrong with my script?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
      var comment = $("#comment"),
      allFields = $([]).add(comment);
      $('#<%= hidden.ClientID %>').val(comment);


      $("#dialog-form").dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          height: 300,
          width: 350,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
              "Add Comment": function () {
                  var bValid = true;
                  allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
                  if (bValid) {
                      $("#comments tbody").append("<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + comment.val() + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + "<%=currentUser%>" + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>");

                      $(this).dialog("close");
                      //                          
                  }
              },
              Cancel: function () {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
              }
          },
          close: function () {
              allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
          }
      });

      $("#NewComment")
    .button()
    .click(function () {
        $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");

    });
  });  
    </script>
```

And here is my hidden input field:

```
<input id="hidden" type="hidden" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use an actual Asp.Net `HiddenField` control like this:

**Markup**:

```
<div>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hidden" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
</div>
```

**Code Behind**:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string hidden = this.hidden.Value;
    Response.Write(hidden);
}
```

**Javascript**:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=hidden.ClientID %>").val("Hello, World!");
    });
</script>
```

**Output**: Hello, World!

Comment: passing "hello world!" works fine.  it's when I try passing the variable "comment" that it doesn't work.  I have a JQuery Dialog popup that has an input field in it and an Add Comment Button in it.  The user types a comment and hits the button.  I'm trying to retrieve the comment variable from JQuery.

Comment: You don't exactly mention what variable you are talking about in your question. comment should be comment.val(). What is var comment = $("#comment")? Also you should have a ";" instead of a "," in there.

Comment: var comment = $("#comment") is getting the value of the input field inside of the dialog pop up. Sorry, the id of the input field inside the popup is comment.

Comment: I think I see what you want to do now. But it seems to me "Comment" is a table. If comment is a table, do you want the html of the table inside the hidden field? you do it  like this: $("#comment").html()

Comment: when i response.write(hidden), I am only getting [object, Object]

Comment: yeah, try $("#comment").html(); make sure to include ";" at the end of the line...

Comment: Oh, I apologize, the id of the input field in the pop up is "comment" and the id of the table for my test output is "comments" Poor naming choices, I know, but I am only using the table to show that my pop up is recording correctly

Comment: Any idea why I'm getting [object Object] instead of the value of the variable

Comment: I have tried $("#comment").html(); and when I do that, my popup will not close when hitting the Add Comment button.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It help me too..  :)

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with this line:   `$('#<%= hidden.ClientID %>').val(comment);`  ?
aren't you missing something like comment**.val()**

Still if I were you I would use a simple handler and make a ajax request.