# How to check a JavaScript event event call in code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, code-behind

I have a JavaScript function **func1()** and a service form(service.aspx) with method **central()**.

The module has the following workflow:

1) func1() is called to perform a check.

2) Central() is called and some data is loaded

3) Data is validated and then displayed.

The ***problem***: In method central(), I want to check if func1() was invoked or not. How do I do this?

Comment: When you call the service method, pass in a validation token that was generated in `func1()`

Comment: Ok. But how do I access that token in method central() ? I am kinda novice in javascript handling.

Comment: I think `service class` is misleading here. Guess you have normal form with `central()` page method in code behind. Do you call `central()` from JavaScript (say from within `func1()`)?

Comment: How are you calling `central` at the moment?

Comment: @nvartak No. I dont. I am calling the Central() through another service method. The func1() and central() dont share any relation as of now. But the order of execution is as per given in the question.

Comment: Show the code if possible. It is important to understand the flow in which these methods are being executed.

Comment: Store a validation token in a hidden field and call it in your central() method

Comment: @Akhil R J Can you provide me with some links as a headstart. That would be very helpful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636703/passing-jquery-variable-to-code-behind-in-asp-net